# Fonts : 404 not found, in production environment

Tags: laravel, azure, laravel-5

On Laravel 5.8 I have my fonts set in my public/fonts folder and use them in my .scss

```
@font-face {
   font-family: 'HelveticaNeue";
   src:url("fonts/HelveticaNeue.otf") format("opentype"),
       url('fonts/HelveticaNeue.woff') format('woff');
}
```

The development environment shows the fonts correctly, but my Azure web app doesn't and displays a 404 Not Found.

The configuration of the server sets the root folder as `/public` and npm run prod as been used to generate the `.css` file in `/public/css/app.css`.

`website.com/css/app.css` can be used to access the css but `website.com/fonts/fontname.extension` throws a 404 in the network tab and the following message:

> The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

What am I missing that does not allow the css to find the font I'm using ?

Comment: did you try like `url('/fonts/HelveticaNeue.woff')` ?

Comment: @fmsthird Yes I did, I also tried `./` as well as`../` directly in the .css file but without much success

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main reason it did not work is because `.htaccess` file is only available on a Apache Server.

The Azure server is a ISS server and requires a `web.config` file which had to let the `otf` and `woff` files available for the public.

Therefore, the following had to be put in this file :

```
<staticContent>
    <remove fileExtension=".woff" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
    <remove fileExtension=".otf" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".otf" mimeType="font/otf" />
<staticContent>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try moving your fonts folder to app.css directory.